# SBS 2008 Users report that they are unable to access some web sites

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, internet, windows-sbs-2008, web

Users in a Windows Server 2008 domain may report that some web sites are inaccessible, while others work OK. The inaccessible web sites may be in .uk and .eu Top Level Domains or in certain other TLDs outside of the USA.

Comment: Would the person who down-voted this question please add a comment explaining why - this is a genuine known issue, so I'm confused why it got a down-vote.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a known problem on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Small Business Server 2008. Please see [SBS 2008 DNS stops working after 1 day for .uk, .eu and some other TLDs outside USA](https://serverfault.com/questions/98999) for a full description and solution.